# Load image in background-image (saved in MSSQL - varbinary)

Tags: c#, css, sql-server

I'm saving images into the table using this code:

```
if (FileUploadControl.PostedFile.ContentType.StartsWith("image/", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
    byte[] imagedata = MSImage.ConvertToByte(FileUploadControl);
    if (imagedata != null)
    {
        string param = "@Image";
        SqlParameter sp = spc.Add(new SqlParameter(param, SqlDbType.VarBinary, -1));
        sp.Value = imagedata;
        sql += ", " + Q.C(Database.MSImage) + "=" + param + ", " + Q.C(Database.MSImageType) + "=N'" + FileUploadControl.PostedFile.ContentType + "'";
    }
}
```

And attempting to load it into `background-image` style with this code:

```
string imagedata = MSImage.ConvertToImage((byte[])ms[Database.MSImage]);
if (imagedata != null && ms[Database.MSImageType] != DBNull.Value && ((string)ms[Database.MSImageType]).StartsWith("image/", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
    takzir2.InnerHtml = "<div class='msbgimage' style=\"background-image:url(data:" + (string)ms[Database.MSImageType] + ";base64, " + imagedata + ")\"></div>";
}
```

The problem is that it won't load the image, and when I try inspecting the element, it gets really stuck because the converted `byte` array returned a very long `string` (that sums up in about 650k characters).

This is my `MSImage` class:

```
public class MSImage
{
    public static byte[] ConvertToByte(FileUpload hpf)
    {
        try
        {
            if (hpf.HasFile)
            {
                Stream fs = hpf.PostedFile.InputStream;
                BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
                Byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fs.Length);
                return bytes;
            }
        }
        catch { }
        return null;
    }

    public static string ConvertToImage(byte[] imagedata)
    {
        try
        {
            if (imagedata != null && imagedata.Length > 0)
                return Convert.ToBase64String(imagedata);
        }
        catch { }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Am I saving the image in a wrong way or is it the loading that causes the issue?

### EDIT:

I just found out that this code is the problem:

```
takzir2.InnerHtml = "<div class='msbgimage' style=\"background-image:url(data:" + (string)ms[Database.MSImageType] + ";base64, " + imagedata + ")\"></div>";
```

I tried using a `div` that has `runat="server"` and it worked with `div.Style["background-image"]`, but how can I make it work with `InnerHtml`?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using following Code to convert my Images, maybe you find a difference...

```
static string Image2Base64(Image image)
{
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        byte[] imageBytes = ms.ToArray();
        string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
        return base64String;
    }
}

static Bitmap Base642Image(string base64image)
{
    try
    {
        byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64image);
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
        ms.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
        Bitmap image = (Bitmap)Image.FromStream(ms, true);
        return image;
    }
    catch { return null; }
}
```

I hope this might help you...

Answer (score 0):

I just found the solution (It's a silly one though):

This line of code was causing the problem:

```
takzir2.InnerHtml = "<div class='msbgimage' style=\"background-image:url(data:" + (string)ms[Database.MSImageType] + ";base64, " + imagedata + ")\"></div>";
```

I changed the end of it from:

```
";base64, " + imagedata + ")\"></div>";
```

To:

```
";base64," + imagedata + ")\"></div>";
```

The space between `";base64,"` to `imagedata` was causing it because `InnerHtml` didn't replace the space character with `%20`.